# Как поменять цвет/размер отдельного слова в тексте?

Tags: css, регулярные-выражения, css3

Как поменять цвет/размер отдельного слова в тексте? 
Возможно ли это?
Может через регулярные выражения?

Comment: посредством только css

Comment: запихиваешь это слово в элемент <span></span> и задаешь, что надо. регулярные выражения - это для джаваскрипта.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, посредством только CSS - так сделать нельзя. (По крайней мере способа сделать это на момент написания комментария мне неизвестно).

Это потому что CSS правила оперируют сущностями DOM (и небольшим набором сущностей в DOM не входящих - псевдоэлементами). В DOM нет такого понятия как отдельное слово.

Да, и регулярных выражений в CSS тоже нету. Потому что они там не нужны, языка селекторов для задач решаемых CSS - достаточно.

"Решаемо чистым css" это только если текст статический, не меняется, искать там ничего не надо и Вы тупо вешаете ручками на слово `<span>` а потом его цсской красите.

Так что если хотим странного - вперед учить javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Ну допустим так:

```js
function i1(i1, i2, i3) {
  var i4 = document.getElementById("text");
  i4.innerHTML = i4.innerHTML.replace(i1, "<span style=\"color: " + i2 + "; font-size: " + i3 + "px;\">" + i1 + "</span>");
  return;
}
```

```html
<span id="text">Моё новое предложение</span>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('Моё', '#AAA', '12');">
  Чёрный, 12 пикселей
</button>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('новое', '#F00', '48');">
  Красный, 48 пикселей
</button>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('предложение', '#FFF', '16');">
  Белый, 16 пикселей
</button>
```

Вот [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/mf9obx3L/1/) пример на JSFiddle.

Comment: А теперь сравни код в фиддле и в ответе. Минус, пока не исправишь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, какая важная деталь. Исправил код в вопросе. Просто когда этот JSFiddle создавал проблемы возникли: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559895/jsfiddle-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82 и поменять кое-что пришлось.

Comment: Убрал минус. Но 1. В `onclick` не стоит писать `javascript:`. 2. использование атрибута `onclick` - это нехорошо. 3. `return` лишний. 4. И вообще, моно было сделать сниппет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пункты 1, 2 и 3 - почему? Может у него не только Javascript на странице. Чем `onclick` плох? `return` всегда везде добавляю, он ничем не вредит. Хотя можно его и убрать, да от этого ничего и не изменится. А как сниппеты делать я не умею, не нашёл.

Comment: 1. Обработчик содержит кусок кода. А у кода нет протокола. Протокол `javascript:` парсится как протокол только в href. А в onclick он превращается в метку в коде. И, кажется, какие-то браузеры не умели такое корректно обрабатывать. 2. Просто плохой стиль. Требует наличия всех обработчиков в глобальном пространстве, соответственно оно захламляется и повышается риск случайных пересечений с другими скриптами. Хотя для примера несущественно. Но если бы обработчик добавлялся из кода, то проблем с неработающим фиддлом бы не возникло. 3. Если нет разницы, зачем писать больше? 4. Кнопка Фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0):

На js вот так, по при условии что **вы знаете сколько слов** :

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".symbols");
var str = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML = str.replace(/\b[^\s]+?\b/g, $0 => `<span>${$0}</span>`);
```

```css
.symbols span:first-child{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
.symbols span:nth-child(2){
  color:green;
  font-size:22px;
}
.symbols span:nth-child(3){
  color:orange;
  font-size:14px;
}
.symbols span:nth-child(4){
  color:yellow;
  font-size:18px;
}
.symbols span:nth-child(5){
  color:pink;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="symbols"> 
 lorem ipsum sit ammed dollar
</div>
```

js предоставлен любезным сообществом **ruStackoverflow**