# JSFiddle не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Почему [код](https://jsfiddle.net/mf9obx3L/) не работает? Я в шоке. Такая простейшая элементарная задачка, а мозги отказываются думать.

HTML:

```
<span id="text">Моё новое предложение</span>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('моё', '#000', '12');">
Чёрный, 12 пикселей
</button>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('новое', '#F00', '48');">
Красный, 48 пикселей
</button>
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript: i1('предложение', '#FFF', '16');">
Белый, 16 пикселей
</button>
```

Javasctipt:

```
function i1(i1, i2, i3) {
    var i4 = document.getElementById("text");
  i4.innerHTML = i4.innerHTML.replace(i1, "<span style=\"color: " + i2 + "; font-size: " + i3 + "px;\">" + i1 + "</span>");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию JSFiddle оборачивает то, что вы вставили в поле "Javascript" в `window.onload`.
Поэтому ваша функция `i1` становится видна не глобально, а локально в замыкании. А в обработчике Вы вызываете глобальную.
Это поведение JSFiddle можно изменить нажав на шестеренку рядом со словом "Javascript" в поле "Javascript" и сменить значение комбобокса Load Type. Например на `no wrap in <body>`.

Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Следует добавить, что можно не меняя настроек для js-кода (оборачивание в window.onload может быть весьма полезно) объявлять функции в глобальной области видимости таким образом: `window.i1 = function(...){...}`