# Ошибки в песочнице jsfiddle

Tags: html, sass

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в песочнице всё сломано? Локально у меня все работает за исключением анимации кнопки бургера в крестик и обратно. Что то с синтаксисом или дело в чем то еще?

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/toradorra/c9L8rya7/17/
```

Comment: подключен вроде

Comment: @РустамГимранов хм, попробовала другим способом подключить (скачала файл jquery-3.4.1.min.js и подключила в проект) вообще кнопка меню перестала работать

Comment: @РустамГимранов сdn у меня и был. менюшка открывается, а сама иконка меню нет

Comment: @РустамГимранов скорее всего так и есть. было бы здорово иметь какой-то редактор sass

Comment: @РустамГимранов я нашла проблему) спасибо вам)

Comment: Связанные:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559895/256824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте консоль в браузере:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

У вас не подключена библиотека JQuery. Подключается в панельке слева, под аватаркой: **`Resources`**. Подключайте `cdn` версии.

---

> Undefined variable: "$dark"
>
> Undefined variable: "$orange"
>
> Undefined variable: "$white"

Так же у вас не определены переменные в SASS. Для проверки ошибок в SASS при написании ответа использовался [сервис](http://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php).

Answer (score 5):

Подключение библиотеки jQuery осуществляется через селектор во "вьюпорте" с кодом JS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее открывается блок с выбором различных надстроек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нас интересует раздел "Frameworks & Extensions", там мы и ищем jQuery (он почти внизу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого достаточно нажать "Run" и библиотека будет подключена.